# Regular expression look-around

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract text from my Instagram captions using Google Sheets (I use Zapier beforehand to extract the captions). I have trouble understanding the look around / look behind regular expressions.

This is a part of the text:

```html
                 ❓
-----
: Species distribution is influenced by light availability. The deeper, the darker. Species depending on light, for instance, photosynthetic organisms, only inhabit the top 200 m. In the darker water, organisms found ways to adapt like this viperfish in the video. Do you know how?! Find out on the blog on the featured article.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀
-----
```

I want to catch what is after the "OceanFact: " and before the invisible space (there is an invisible space before the next separator -----). I could also insert a special word that would signal the end of the string if the invisible space doesn't work.

How would you code that? I have tried many things in a regex editor but can't manage to catch what I want.
I thought `(?![OceanFact]+\:\s+)\w(?!⠀)` would do the trick but not sure it is the best (the parenthesis contains the invisible character).

It partially works in this [editor](https://regexr.com/) but not in Google Spreadsheet. I can't manage to take the space and punctuation marks between "`OceanFact:` " and the "⠀" invisible character.
Not sure where I fail.

Any clue?

Comment: It seems you need `/:\s*([^\u2800]+)/.exec(text)[1]`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, ": (.+)\n")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works. However, if I would want to add space between paragraphs, it would not catch the text correctly. How would I stop at the invisible space character: "⠀" or an emoji?
Not sure google spreadsheet supports unicode...

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with example?

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet. The extract are on the third. The annoying thing is that we were not consistent from the start :D
So you'll see many patterns. I have managed to extract part of them that I copy in the "cleaned database" sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11nZ57xpOLdnEA9HuK34_EdWU0_sTdFvDPWqqIHtS-Pw/edit?usp=sharing